# ESlint reports an error when I call my parent's function

Tags: angularjs, eslint

In my child controller I am calling a function from its parent using $scope. Everything works fine but when I run gulp serve I get an ESLint Error

> You should not set properties on $scope in controllers. Use
>   controllerAs syntax and add data to "this"

So my question is how should I handle this the right way?

Here is what I do explained in more details:

I am using UIRouter in my Angular project. I have declared a parent state and its child state.

```
$stateProvider.state('app.parent', {
  url: '/parent',
  temolateUrl: 'parent.html',
  contorller: 'MyParentController as parentCtrl'
}


$stateProvider.state('app.parent.child', {
  url: '/child',
  temolateUrl: 'child.html',
  contorller: 'MyChildController as childCtl'
}
```

In my parent controller I added my function to the $scope so that the function could be accessed from state's child.

```
function MyParentController() {
  $scope.myParentFunction = myParentFunction;
  function myParentFunction(){
    //do something
  }
}
```

In my child state (controller) i call this function.

```
function MyChildController(){
...
  $scope.myParentFunction();
...
}
```

Everything works but when I run gulp serve I get an ESLint Error

> You should not set properties on $scope in controllers. Use
>   controllerAs syntax and add data to "this"

So my question is how should I handle this the right way.

Answer (score 0):

you should use controllerAs syntax

https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

```
function MyChildController($scope){
    var vm = this;
    vm.scope = $scope;
    vm.scope.myParentFunction();    
}
```

Comment: I think this would remove ESLint warning but it looks like a workaround and not a solution. I am still using a $scope instead of this.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I tried turn off all .eslintrc's value to false. but still did not work.